# Search in a HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table, href

I'm trying to create a search field on an HTML page which scans the table and opens the corresponding href to that entry in the table.

As an example if you were to enter and submit `Xbox` into the search field it would open the link(*product.html*) associated with `Xbox`.

```js
function tableSearch() {
  var eingabe = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
  return alert($("table td:contains(eingabe)")
    .children("a")
    .attr("href"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="tableSearch()">
  Product name: <br> <input type="text" name="input">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<table class="firsttable" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Camera</td>
    <td>239 g</td>
    <td>10,8cm* 5,5cm * 5,5cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>10,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Monitor</td>
    <td>2,8 kg</td>
    <td>17,3 inch</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>449 &euro;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a href="product.html">Xbox</a> </td>
    <td>3,6 kg</td>
    <td>43,3cm * 35,7cm * 10,6cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>299,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I tried changing the JavaScript code but could not get it working. Hope someone here can help!

Comment: You need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` with your `input`.

Comment: Note: the `align` attribute is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you could attach the `input` event to track the user input's :

```
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var eingabe = $(this).val();

  var href = $("table td:contains(" + eingabe + ")").find("a").attr("href");

  location.href = href; // will redirect you to the page in your href
})
```

Code:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var eingabe = $(this).val();

  console.log($("table td:contains(" + eingabe + ")").find("a").attr("href"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Camera</td>
    <td>239 g</td>
    <td>10,8cm* 5,5cm * 5,5cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>10,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monitor</td>
    <td>2,8 kg</td>
    <td>17,3 inch</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>449 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="product.html">Xbox</a></td>
    <td>3,6 kg</td>
    <td>43,3cm * 35,7cm * 10,6cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>299,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` with your `input` to get its value.

And by writing `return alert("")` you are not returning anything, you need to click this `a` link instead of alerting it's `href` to move to the product page.

This is how should be your function:

```
function tableSearch() {
  var eingabe = document.getElementById('input').value;
  $("table td:contains(" + eingabe + ")").find("a").click();
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function tableSearch() {
  var eingabe = document.getElementById('input').value;
  $("table td:contains(" + eingabe + ")").find("a").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="tableSearch()"> Product name: <br> <input type="text" name="input"> <br> <input type="submit" value="submit"> </form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Camera</td>
    <td>239 g</td>
    <td>10,8cm* 5,5cm * 5,5cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>10,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monitor</td>
    <td>2,8 kg</td>
    <td>17,3 inch</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>449 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="product.html">Xbox</a></td>
    <td>3,6 kg</td>
    <td>43,3cm * 35,7cm * 10,6cm</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>299,99 &euro;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So I've got this form on my HTML page :  
  
<form  onsubmit="tableSearch()"> Product name:  <br>
  <input type="text" name="input"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">  
  </form>

On submit I'm trying to execute the function. And this is how my function looks like now : 

function tableSearch() {
  var eingabe = document.getElementById('input').value
  $("table td:contains(" + eingabe + ")").find("a").click();
}

Is there still any logical error, because in my eyes everything looks correct?

Comment: @PerKosmos I updated the Demo in my answer and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I just added your code to my code but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ? I've got the searchbox, and whenever I type something into it, it adds it in the URL Bar as an "input=Xbox"  ... am I missing something ? Copied your function into my JS script

Comment: @PerKosmos It should work, may be you are doing something else, can you make a [**Fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net), with your new code?

Comment: @PerKosmos you need to click on `Save` before copying the path of the fiddle.